# ld: library not found for -lplot

Tags: c, fink

I am new here. I recently installed plotutils-dev on my mac using fink, but when I try to compile a little program I have by doing

```
gcc -g -o atomos.o atomos.c -lplot
```

it says

```
ld: library not found for -lplot
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have searched the problem on the web with little success. The only thing I know is that when I type

```
dpkg -S libplot.dylib
```

it says

```
plotutils-dev: /sw/lib/libplot.dylib
```

which I believe it means I have installed libplot on my mac. So I don't know what is the problem. Any help is welcomed. I am a beginner so It would be nice if some guidelines are provided in a user-friendly way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linker can't find the libplot library. I'm not familiar with mac, but with gcc you can tell it the path to the library with the -L flag, e.g.:

```
gcc -g -o atomos.o atomos.c -lplot -L/sw/lib/
```

(I'm guessing at that path, but you can probably figure out the path to the library if that isn't right.)

Also, it's probably a typo in your question, but I changed it to `-lplot` (note extra `-l`). You want the -l to link with the plot library.

Comment: Happy to have helped. If this solved your problem, you can click the big green check mark next to the answer to mark it as accepted.